# How to reset ls command functionality

Tags: command-line, 18.04

This is kinda embarrassing, but I have an Ubuntu console on my windows' software that I used to use in 2019 and left behind when i installed Ubuntu itself. Today i tried using it and found that i changed the function of the ls command to display "Hello World" instead of the normal ls functionality.
So is there a way to reset ls's functionality to its default one ?

This is the output of `type -a ls`

```
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
```

Comment: Have you tried running `ls` in different directories? The "occam's razor" explanation is that your current directory contains a single file named `Hello World`. What happens with `ls -l` or `/bin/ls -l`? What does `file /bin/ls` say?

Comment: it works fine in other directories. 
and `` file /bin/ls `` result is ```/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9567f9a28e66f4d7ec4baf31cfbf68d0410f0ae6, stripped ```

and when i type `` ls -l`` 
it outputs -rw-r--r-- 1 kkhater kkhater 5 Dec 28  2019 'Hello World'

Comment: ... right - so Occam was correct ;)

Comment: Yes, that means that you have a single file in the directory named "Hello World". *of course* that's what `ls` will display when you call it :)

Comment: yup that was it :)
i guess i trolled myself two years in the future lol

Comment: For the exact thing you experienced, don't add the current directory to the beginning of the path. If you _really_ want the current directory, put it at the end so that a command in your current directory won't override 'standard' ones like `ls`. If you have it at the beginning, and go into some downloaded folder, and it has a malicious `ls` file, and you do `ls`, the bad one will run. If the current dir is at the end, the real one will take priority and save you.